# Dismiss activity in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent

I am using the following code to show “Hello” message with ok button when the user clicks a button. In some applications this is working fine. ie while clicking the ok button, the activity is dismissed. But in one application, this is not getting dismissed after clicking the ok button. What to do? Please help.

```
public class MyClass extends Activity {
    private TextView labelTxt;
    private Button okBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.message);

        labelTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
        labelTxt.setText("Hello");
        okBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.okBtn);
        okBtn.setOnClickListener(okBtnClickListener);
    }

    private final OnClickListener okBtnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();            
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: does you get any error?

Comment: no error.. but it is hanging on the ok button

Comment: try to debug it on device that doent executing the onclicklistener

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have tested your code and modified little. Please check below

```
package test.stackoverflow;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOK);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try like this....

```
okBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                finish();// Closing Activity
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your layout make sure your Button is named:

```
android:id="@+id/okBtn"
.....
```

Did you import:

```
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
```

Please look at this tutorial, it should help:

http://martin.cubeactive.com/android-onclicklitener-tutorial/